# Add Total Row For Columns D - M

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2013

I have been using this syntax to add a total row for column D - but now I need to add the total row for D - M.  Instead of just writing this code multiple times and changing the column name is there a quick re-usable function that could add a total row to the bottom of columns D - M?

```
With ActiveSheet
If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Cells) <> 0 Then
    lastrow = .Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                  After:=.Range("D1"), _
                  Lookat:=xlPart, _
                  LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                  SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                  SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                  MatchCase:=False).Row
Else
    lastrow = 1
End If
End With
Range("D" & lastrow +1).FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(R[-" & lastrow & "]C:R[-1]C)"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has the same effect as highlighting that range and hitting Ctrl+Right Arrow

```
range("D" & lastrow + 1 & ":M" & lastrow + 1).FillRight
```

Comment: Excellent, got my answer and learned a new VBA function.  Thank you!